# what should i do, if aws accidentally remove my instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, system-administration

I'm a regular aws user and last week one of my accounts was under hold due to account verification. During this period of time, I can't access my aws account and my running instance is stopped. Last weekend they removed the account hold issue, and I can access my aws account. But the problem is there are no instances. I have a client and I run their CRM In that instance, it is a production server.I submitted a ticket and after 3 days they agreed that during the account verification time they apparently deleted my instance. I haven't got any updates till now. It's already 10 days. The customer is frustrating me because they want the running CRM. I don't have any backup for the database. Anyone who has had the same issue before, please share your experience and please suggest any idea about what step I should take next.

I have the email chat and all the records.

Comment: No way to recover anything. next time you can use Amazon EBS snapshots or Amazon Machine Images (AMI) to backup. [Check this out](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recovery-terminated-instance/)

Comment: Amazon may still have a backup of the machine but if not nothing you can do, always take your own backups weekly as any managed database host would and perform updates then. Assume you data can be deleted, hardware can fail all sorts.

Comment: This sounds like you need to file a ticket with AWS support instead of asking random strangers on the Internet for help.

Comment: Make sure you are looking in the correct Region. If you look in the wrong Region, it will not appear. It is quite unusual for AWS to delete resources.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have any backup for the database.

Then your database is gone. Sadly you have to start from scratch and make sure in future to make backups.

Comment: i have had a similar situation where database was refreshed, luckily I had the backups - Cannot emphasise more on this that always have backups of your data. Take daily snapshots so that you don't end up in such scenarios.

Comment:  but it's not my fault, all the actions performed by aws team. So they responsible to get back my data,right?

Comment: @jeraldjacob - only a lawyer can answer that for you.

Comment: @jeraldjacob AWS (nor any other cloud provide) does not guarantee 100% reliability for any of its services. So you always have to assume that something may fail.

Comment: @Marcin but in this case, they deleted the my instance not from my side. So the reliability related concern is not covered my case. It's deleted by their employees , so it does not cover any other kind of concessions.

Comment: @jeraldjacob Ok, just talk to the layer, Maybe you have a case against AWS.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the updates. Is there any portal or community is available to address this issue in top authorities ?